# Failed Binder Transaction While playing video on Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I got an app which will loops a video infinite times until new video is sent to the app. I am getting below error in between  8000 to 12000 playbacks

**Error**

```
07-21 06:25:35.105: W/MediaPlayer(26830): info/warning (3, 0)
07-21 06:25:35.105: I/MediaPlayer(26830): Info (3,0)

07-21 06:25:35.135: E/JavaBinder(26830): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Video freezes after the JavaBinder error. I have to restart the app to make it work.

Created a class which extends VideoView and all the playback's and video handling happen in this class

```
public class VideoPlayView extends VideoView
```

**onCompletion** method

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    super.start();      
}
```